# need help to understand this PHP api and access it using Ruby

Tags: php, ruby, api, rest, sugarcrm

Here is the documentation for the SugarCRM 5.5 API:

**set_relationship**

http://developers.sugarcrm.com/docs/PRO/5.5/Developer_Guides/-docs-Developer_Guides-Sugar_Developer_Guide_5.5.1-Chapter%202%20Application%20Framework.html#9000526

This is the gem which is creating methods for me to access it (line 110):

http://github.com/dennijo/Ruby-Sugar/blob/master/lib/ruby_sugar/client.rb

QUESTION:  What is the actual format with an example for me to make a relationship between an Account and a Contact?  I am confused in terms of what to pass.  It *looks* like the API requires 5 parameters, but the gem only passes two.  The documentation for the gem says to pass a hash as follows:

```
Assumes:
  @client = RubySugar::Client.new(user,pass,url,true)

  def set_relationship(mod,id,related,related_id)
    data = [
      {:module1=>mod,:moudule1_id=>id.to_s,:module2=>related,:module2_id=>related_id.to_s}
    ]
    @client.set_relationship(data)
  end
```

Comment: does the ruby-sugar gem have a mailing list? if not maybe ping the author

Answer (score 1):

I think you're getting confused between the actual sugar-api (which says to use five parameters) and the "api" of the *gem* (which uses just the hash of values).

Line 110 of the gem (as you described) only uses two parameters - but again, that is a call to a *ruby* method... which is no doubt defined elsewhere in the code.

No doubt, somewhere inside the sugar gem - it will turn that hash into the real parameters to pass to Sugar... but all you need to worry about is populating the hash correctly, which should be covered in the docs.